# Unable to translate "newsletter" in the newsletter preview title

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, newsletter

It seems that translation for "newsletter" word in the title of [newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) preview is not possible yet, e.g. for rusSE:

> [image: rusSE]

Same situation appears for all localized Stack Overflow sites, except for ruSO, where the custom image is used instead of the text:

> [image: ruSO]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (>= `2019.2.25.32934`)

Comment: Could you please post a string id for Transifex, or link to the traducir?

Comment: [here you go](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/132799977?q=key%3A7b494069a83292955249a470bcf7b20f)

Comment: thanks, please, see the linked new question.