# Newsletter title fix colors the wrong element

Tags: bug, design, localization, newsletter

One of my previous [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324418/339911) was fixed according to the developer’s answer but the fix has introduced a new problem. In particular there is something odd with text coloring:

> [image: odd color]

For English based sites full word “Newsletter” is colored:

> [image: English newsletter]

It seems that code unconditionally colors the last one word of the sentence. In the case of the Russian newsletter, the non-word (`»`) is colored instead of the words that mean "newsletter" - "Новостные рассылки".

Comment: Which word is actually the equivalent of "newsletter"? Presumably, that's the one that needs to be colored differently.

Comment: @Catija the equivalent are first two words. I suggest to add into source (English) string start/stop markers to allow translators decide, which part of the text will be colored.

Comment: Thanks, @αλεχολυτ  I've edited to clarify which part of the phrase is supposed to be light blue. Hopefully we can find a way to address this. I'm guessing that, since the sites are generally in English, it was easy to just make the last word blue but this hasn't scaled with our five non-English sites.

Comment: @Catija as far as I see, for some sites the image is used instead of the text, this could be solution too.